# Challenges using scope (Angular.js)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on an assignment and have found some challenges with my angular app. I have a folder, which contains `dishtail.html` and `app.js` but I have found some challenges in the view, that is the controller for `DishDetailController` is not displaying the description, label or image. Below is the code for the `dishtail.html` and the `app.js`. I have been going through the code to find where I am doing wrong but haven't found any. Please I need help to locate where my mistakes are. Thank you.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp', [])

        .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.tab = 1;
            $scope.filtText = '';
            $scope.showDetails = false;

            $scope.dishes=[
                         {
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comment: ''
                        },
                        {
                          name:'Zucchipakoda', 
                          image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                          category: 'appetizer', 
                          label:'',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                           comment: ''
                        },
                        {
                          name:'Vadonut', 
                          image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                          category: 'appetizer', 
                          label:'New',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                           comment: ''
                        },
                        {
                          name:'ElaiCheese Cake', 
                          image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                          category: 'dessert', 
                          label:'',
                          price:'2.99',
                          description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                           comment: ''
                        }
                        ];

            $scope.select = function(setTab) {
                $scope.tab = setTab;

                if (setTab === 2) {
                    $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
                }
                else if (setTab === 3) {
                    $scope.filtText = "mains";
                }
                else if (setTab === 4) {
                    $scope.filtText = "dessert";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.filtText = "";
                }
            };

            $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
                return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
            };

            $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
                $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
            };
        }])

        .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };

            var channels = [{value:"tel", label:"Tel."}, {value:"Email",label:"Email"}];

            $scope.channels = channels;
            $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;

        }])

        .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.sendFeedback = function() {

                console.log($scope.feedback);

                if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel == "")) {
                    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
                    console.log('incorrect');
                }
                else {
                    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
                    $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };
                    $scope.feedback.mychannel="";
                    $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
                    console.log($scope.feedback);
                }
            };
        }])

        .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            var dish={
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                    };

            $scope.dish = dish;

        }])

        .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form

            $scope.submitComment = function () {

                //Step 2: This is how you record the date
                "The date property of your JavaScript object holding the comment" = new Date().toISOString();

                // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
                $scope.dish.comments.push("Your JavaScript Object holding the comment");

                //Step 4: reset your form to pristine

                //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
            }
        }])

;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                   <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
                        </a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                         <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                         <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the question here?  you just threw a bunch of code here and said "tell me what's wrong".  That's not a good question.

Comment: As @Claies asked, do explain what is the problem you are facing or the error you got. Just out of curiosity, is there 2 versions of angular defined? One even before Doctype and another towards the end?